# Setting a list to a field in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following in my `values.yaml`

```yaml
router:
  env:
    - name: JSON_LOGGING
      value: True
```

In my `Deployment` I would simply like to set this list to the `env` field like so:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    # ..
    env: {{ $.Values.router.env }}
```

However, it appears that this produces an incorrect YAML file:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on translation/templates/translation-router.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 35: did not find expected ',' or ']'
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inline part of your configuration using `toYaml`.

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    # ..
    env:
      {{- toYaml .Values.rounter.env | nindent 6 }}
```